# How to make Decision Tree rules more understandable?

Tags: r, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I'd like to extract useful rules from Decision Trees/Random Forest in order to develop a more applicable way to handle the rules and predictions. So I need an application which makes the rules more understandable.

Any suggestions (e.g. visualizations, validation methods etc) for my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as WHY a particular split was chosen, the answer is always going to be: "Because that split created the best splitting of the target variable."

You referenced [`scikit-learn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/)... Go ahead and briefly scan scikit-learn's [documentation on Decision Trees](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html)... It has an example, which is exactly what you are asking for in the middle of the page.  It looks like this:

[image: graphical representation of decision tree]

The code to generate this plot is there also:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris()
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
with open("iris.dot", 'w') as f:
f = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=f)
```

There are several other graphical representations there also with accompanying code:

[image]
[image]

The SKL documentation is generally awesome and is very useful.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like **overfitting** to me. Maybe it would be more understandable if it weren't overfitted that much?

Comment: That's the point of the plot... max depth of 5 is clearly overfit, but max depth of 2 is also shown e.g. these types of plots help you choose a model, but you have to see which depth leads to overfitting and which depths lead to underfitting in order to choose the right depth.

Comment: Thanks for the references. This is a great starting point! Besides that, I search for a method to build a **business application** on top of rules from the decision trees. Something like "Credit Scoring" (see: [Guide to Credit Scoring in R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Sharma-CreditScoring.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

While this is certainly possible for Decision Trees and AN6U5 did a great job describing how, Random Forests use bundles of little trees that were trained using random subsets of the data and random subsets of the features. Thus each tree is optimal only in that limited setting of features and data. Since there are typically 100s or even 1000s of them, figuring out the context by examining the randomized data is going to be a thankless task. I don't think anyone does it.

However there are importance ranking for the features generated for Random Forests and pretty much all implementations will output them if requested. They turn out to be extremely useful.

Two of the most important ones are MDI (Mean Decrease Impurity) and MDA (Mean Decrease Accuracy). They are described in some detail in chapter 6 of this excellent work: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.7502v3.pdf

Comment: Yes, I agree @Mike Wise, switching from decision trees to random forests changes the scope of visualization considerations significantly. I think one has to visualize the decision tree and then not worry too much in moving toward random forests.  Those newer to machine learning and data science tend to be overly oriented toward discovery of "take-home heuristics" and under concerned with proper model validation through model metrics, ROC curves, bias-variance decomposition, etc.  My suggestion would be to employ these types of methods and not try to visualize the entire random forest of trees.

Comment: Completely agree. I use a lot of RT and BTs in my work and the good thing about RT is the importance metrics. Btw, I loved your answer and will look into those things have not seen it. And I hope Iomaga remembers to mark your answer correct. :) Note that if he had a few more points he could upvote too...

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, references and discussion about the validation methods of DT/RF. They turned out to be extremly useful for my task. BTW I marked AN6U5 as the correct answer.